# ejabberd ACL for specific chatrooms

Tags: access-control-list, ejabberd, xmpp, instant-messaging

Is it possible (if yes, how) to implement per-chatroom deny/allow styled ACL for users or groups in [ejaberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ACL per user can be configured via [affiliations](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#affil) in jabber chatroom.

In my case setting a Jabber chatroom as member's only and adding the desired users as members via the command affiliate.

**A quick example of configuring a sort of an ACL for a specified chatroom with [pidgin](http://pidgin.im/).**

1. `/config` while on the desired chatroom brings up the configuration options for the current room. Selecting the option 'Member's Only' allows only members to enter the room.
2. `/affiliate Jon Pon member` sets Jon and Pon as members on the current chatroom.

There are more options and combinations but this worked in my case.